# Camp Null even with NOT NULL

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm really noob on ***MySQL***, and I think this is an easy question!

I have this to create my table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tabelapontos` (
  `steamid` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `exp` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `pontos` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `nivel` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

But sometimes *SteamID* still gets null, like this:

[image]

This is the stats from a player, that without any reason *SteamID* turns into a null value.

Can you tell me why?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You create the table IF NOT EXISTS. Maybe it existed before and steamid was nullable there?

Answer (score 2):

You can get this output if steamid is "" (empty string) etc., there is really nothing to indicate that steamid is null.

Comment: +1. Being an Oracle person, I completely forgot that empty strings are not null elsewhere.